# Counting offsets of structure fields

Tags: struct

i have the following question:

For example, when I have the structure

```
    IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER STRUCT         |   C1    |    C2      
    Name1                     BYTE      |   +0    |    +0
    union Misc                          |
        PhysicalAddress       DWORD     |    2    |     2
        VirtualSize           DWORD     |    6    |
    ends                                |
    VirtualAddress            DWORD     |    10   |     6
    SizeOfRawData             DWORD     |    14   |     10
    PointerToRawData          DWORD     |    18   |     14
       ...(etc.)
```

Then how I must count the offsets? The columns C1 and C2 represent my solutions but i am not sure which of the two is right or if both are wrong.
Do I have to consider the union in the structure as 1 field, or do I need to consider its fields separately?

best regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A union is a list of fields *starting at the same address in memory* (except for bitfields, of course). Its size is at least the size of the largest field in it. In your case, it would be 4 bytes.

Note that, like structs, the size can be bigger due to alignment requirements. For example, take this C union:

```
union MyUnion {
    char a[5];
    int b;
};
```

The `a` fields is 5 bytes, `b` is 4. You would expect the union to be 5 bytes, but, as you can check with `sizeof(union MyUnion)`, it is actually 8. This is because `int`s are aligned to a 4-byte boundary. Similiarly, `short`s are aligned to 2 bytes and `double`s to 8. [Try it on CodingGround](http://goo.gl/yzwlrX).

You may be asking yourself: why does the compiler align the union *size*? Isn't aligning the *starting address* enough? It could well keep the size of `MyUnion` to 5 and align the start to a 4-byte boundary for the int. The problem comes when you have an array of the union. An array needs to be a *contiguous* block of memory because of how array and pointer arithmetic works. Given a generic `T array[]` you have that `array[i] == *(array + i) == *((T *) (((char *) array) + i * sizeof(T)))`. In the example case, `MyUnion` has a 4-byte alignment requirement (the largest aligment in the union). If you have a `MyUnion array[]`, the starting address will be 4-byte aligned because of the int. This means that `array[0]` will be correctly aligned. But if the size of the union is 5, then `array[1]` will be at a 5 bytes offset from the starting address. This is not 4-byte aligned! Aligning the union size to 8 bytes puts `array[1]` to a 8 bytes offset, which is 4-bytes aligned. Aligning the size by padding the union allows the array to be contiguous while keeping everything aligned.

**Bottom line:**

**In a union (or a struct), both the *starting address* and the *size* are aligned to the biggest alignment requirement of the fields.**

Of course, alignment requirements may vary between compilers and architectures. Keep that in mind.

Neither C1 nor C2 is correct as far as I can see, since the first field is a byte and not two:

```
IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER STRUCT         |w/o align| aligned |
Name1                     BYTE      |   +0    |   +0    |
union Misc                          |   +1    |   +4    |
    PhysicalAddress       DWORD     |         |         |
    VirtualSize           DWORD     |         |         |            
ends                                |         |         |
VirtualAddress            DWORD     |   +5    |   +8    |
SizeOfRawData             DWORD     |   +9    |   +12   |
PointerToRawData          DWORD     |   +13   |   +16   |
   ...(etc.)
```

Comment: Reading the answer again I realized I wasn't very clear. The `int` *alignment* is making the size 8 bytes. This has to do with arrays. I updated the answer, please check it. I also updated the CodingGound sample to show alignment.